# cifs mount failing after 16.04.1 upgrade (lts-xenial kernel)

Tags: 16.04, samba, cifs

I have two `CIFS` shares which both mounted fine on 14.04 and 16.04. When I apply 16.04.1, the one is now not mounting at all, but giving:

```
mount -t cifs <CIFS SHARE> <Linux Mount point> -o username=<username>
Password for *****:
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs>
```

The other share actually mounts, however not showing any content. Knowing the sub folders I can do a cd, and actually see the sub folders.

So seems like some permission issue, however I have full control privilege on both, and as mentioned, worked fine until the `xenial-kernel update`.
Any ideas/suggestions to what whas changed (and in particular, what I should change to make it work again)?

Comment: Sorry, that text came out quite bad. anyway, my mount command is fine, includes the share and mount point, and works fine up until 16.04.1

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible anymore by default. Here is a walkthrough [Mount Cifs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

There is a note on the page:

Note: Regretfully as from version 3.3.2-1ubuntu3.2 (October 2009) this approach is no longer possible together with the "user" option. A security fix prevents reading the credentials file if you don't have read access to it. You will have to pin the packages at version 3.3.2-1ubuntu3 or 3.3.2-1ubuntu3.1 to continue using this approach as non-root.

Try something like this

```
mount -t cifs //server/share/directory /mnt/directory -ocredentials=/path/to/cifs.credentials,nodfs
```

Comment: yes, that issues seems to be pretty old. I have the same issue when using credentials file. One share is mounted without read permission (but with execute), another is reported as not existing. the userid has full control on both shares, and exactly the same mount command worked fine before 16.04.1

Comment: One other question do you have cifs-utils installed?

Comment: yes, cifs-utils is installed. I have managed to mount the shares using a direct path to the shares, rather than a domain prefixed. So now I am just wondering why that was suddenly required.